# Cannot get pages or posts to display

Tags: configuration, installation

I am trying to set up Wordpress for a client who uses XO Communications as a host.  However, getting Wordpress set up is driving me nuts.  I keep getting this error message *(wrapping message for clarity)*:

```
Warning: main(./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php) 
[function.main]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /web/wordpress/index.php on line 17
```

I have manually installed the latest release of WP. The admin area is working fine.

I set my general configurations as:

- WP: http://newyorkharborschool.org/wordpress
- Site: newyorkharborschool.org/wordpress

I modified the index file with this code: `require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');`

I checked and wp-blog-header exists and is in the wordpress directory.

I have tried reinstalling Wordpress. None of that worked.

I tried downgrading Wordpress: XO offers a one-click installation of an old (2.2.3) version of Wordpress. After downgrading, pages and posts displayed. However, when I upgraded I get the above error message.

Thank you for any help. This is driving me nuts!
Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Did you get clean copy of WordPress for reinstall (like went and downloaded from wordpres.org)? That line should be following ([SVN](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/index.php))

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

And it absolutely should not be edited since it is part of WordPress core.

Answer (score 0):

what's this for?

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

and if you want to include file in wordpress directory which is **below** your current dir:

```
require('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I deleted my Wordpress installation  and loaded a fresh copy, including the original index.php.

My new installation is in the root directory with the files of the static site.

Things still don't work:  all pages and posts go to the  home page of the static site.  

I changed the Permalink structure a few times. When I did a custom structure (/%postname%/) I got a 404 error.

Is this an issue with the .htaccess file?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In order to get the latest release of Wordpress working in  its own directory on an XO Communications server, I installed the Disable Canonical URLs plugin: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/24/how-to-disable-wordpress-canonical-url-or-permalink-auto-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

```
In order to get the latest release of Wordpress working in its own directory on an XO Communications server, I installed the Disable Canonical URLs plugin:
```

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/24/how-to-disable-wordpress-canonical-url-or-permalink-auto-redirect/